# Preloading css hover images using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Does anybody know a good way to preload css hover images using jQuery?

What I'd ideally like is to be able to add a class (say "`pre-load-hover`") to any element that should be pre-loaded, and then put some js in `$(document).ready()` to loop through any DOM elements with that class, find their css background-image and load it up.

The problem is I can't work out a way to easily get to the hover image location.  The jQuery selector `:hover` does not seem to work.

I also don't want to load all the stylesheets and search for the selector by some sort of string search.

Comment: You should use sprite sheets. :) http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Answer (score 7):

I think you should try with CSS sprites. This is a technique where you use one image which contains both the normal image and the hover image. Then you just play with the margin (using negative margin) to show the appropriate image. You can read this article about [CSS sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites).

Comment: http://spritegen.website-performance.org/ Is a pretty useful tool to generate sprites.

Comment: -1 - This doesn't answer the question. CSS sprites have their use cases, but are not always the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Serg it actually answers the question by giving an alternative solution which is still an answer. I would say that this is much better than using image preloading especially for hover images.

Answer (score 3):

This is a small snipped i am using to preload images:

```
preload = (function () {
    var images = [];

    return function () {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

        while (args.length > 0) {
            images.unshift(new Image());
            images[0].src = args.shift();
        }
    }
}());
```

Usage:

```
preload('http://example.com/some_image.png' /* , 'http://example.com/some_other_image.png' ... */);
preload.apply(this, ['http://example.com/some_image.png' /* , 'http://example.com/some_other_image.png' ... */]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look over here:

This is a special plugin for jquery.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/automated_image_preloader

Answer (score 1):

There are a [few plugins out there for this already](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/update_automatically_preload_images_from_css_with_jquery/), check them out.  For the other portion, `:hover` isn't a valid selector, not when querying *other* elements (pretty much, *always* avoid using it in a selector, since it doesn't work cross-browser).

Comment: +1 for the correct answer. Sidenote: `:hover` works fine when used on `a` elements. At least in all major browsers out there (based on Trident, Presto, WebKit and Gecko). Edit regarding your link: Are they really parsing CSS using JavaScript? I do not think that this is a good idea...

Comment: @elusive - for applying CSS yes, not in a jQuery selector...what elements would you be selecting?

Answer (score 0):

You could take your sprites one step further and make a sheet of them and request the images by coordinates. Bigger companies like Google and Yahoo are doing this to lower server requests (because they're only using one image request to show multiple images).

[Google sprite sheet example](http://www.google.com/images/nav_logo16.png)

Call specific images with coordinates in CSS:

```
.image1
{
    background: url(spritesheet.png) -30px -30px no-repeat;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}


.image2
{
    background: url(spritesheet.png) -120px -50px no-repeat;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

Put some spacing in between the icons though, because some mobile browsers (like Safari on the iPad) have trouble with cutting the background image off correctly.

Comment: How is this different from normal CSS-sprites?

Comment: It's the exact same. But I see people making separate images for each image they want a hover state for. Which isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

http://binarykitten.me.uk/dev/jq-plugins/11-jquery-image-preloader.html
usage: $.preLoadImages(['/images/1.png', '/images/2.png', '/images/3.png']);